# slice and merge 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

is there a good way to slice and merge 2 arrays based on empty values for example

first array

```
      0 => string 'Perfect all gorgeous and arrived in less than 1 month for brazil' (length=64)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'Good figures for their money, only instead of bits normal stick child bit rastroilsya' (length=85)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
      5 => string '' (length=0)
```

second array

```
 0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string 'http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8jjnecFfFXKJk43Otq6xIPFXaw.jpg" data-eid="eid-201782563197' (length=88)
      2 => string 'http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/UTB87.bdcNHEXKJk43Jeq6yeeXXaZ.jpg" data-eid="eid-201782563197' (length=88)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string 'http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8cxXwg4HEXKJk43Jeq6yeeXXam.jpg" data-eid="eid-201833045441' (length=88)
      5 => string 'http://g04.a.alicdn.com/kf/UTB824Xwg4HEXKJk43Jeq6yeeXXaB.jpg" data-eid="eid-201833045441' (length=88)
```

I want them to be like this array

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'comment' => string 'Perfect all gorgeous and arrived in less than 1 month for brazil' (length=64)
      'images' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8jjnecFfFXKJk43Otq6xIPFXaw.jpg" data-eid="eid-201782563197' (length=88)
          1 => string 'http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/UTB87.bdcNHEXKJk43Jeq6yeeXXaZ.jpg" data-eid="eid-201782563197' (length=88)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'comment' => string 'Good figures for their money, only instead of bits normal stick child bit rastroilsya' (length=85)
      'images' => 
        array (size=2)
          3 => string 'http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8cxXwg4HEXKJk43Jeq6yeeXXam.jpg" data-eid="eid-201833045441' (length=88)
          4 => string 'http://g04.a.alicdn.com/kf/UTB824Xwg4HEXKJk43Jeq6yeeXXaB.jpg" data-eid="eid-201833045441' (length=88)
```

How to do it ?

Comment: In your second array, there's no way we can know that element 4 and 5 belong with element 3 of the first array. AND, if you're relying on the empty elements as a way to group them, that's really bad design.

Comment: Where are those arrays coming from? Do you produce them yourself? Then  don't go further with this. Instead redesign your original data structure.

Comment: I concur with Brian. It looks like you're doing something with the data already that you probably shouldn't. Where does it come from? Is it the result of an API request or DB query?

Comment: I wrote based on empty values   first 2 for first comment  and the third & forth pictures for second comment.  the number determined by empty value between them

Comment: We can see how it matches, but we are all saying you are already on the wrong path with those two arrays. Redesign the source.

Comment: I look them using curl and them group them by preg_match

Comment: I can't  design them  since I took them from certain website based on inserted url.  for example if  I want comments from a product page it will fetch these comments, so I don't have control over them

Comment: @AhmadzIssa What is the original shape of the data? That will almost certainly be a better starting point than this

Comment: It would probably be more interesting as a question if you would provide the data you get via curl. Because it is very likely there are better ways to get to the final structure.

Comment: Right, so we have an "x/y problem" here: you've started down a particular road and got stuck, and rather than looking for ways to climb over the roadblock, you need to back up and look for a different route. Go back to the original response you got from curl, and think of ways to get the data you need without all this magic blank entry business.

Comment: @IMSoP  the curl  brings the page content after sending appropriate headers info, so there's nothing I can do with curl  then  I match the content and croup them as array using  preg_match_all and then I got these two arrays since I have 2 groups.

Comment: Don't start messing around with the data using regexes. We need to see it as you got it from the server.

Comment: Right, it's the "match the content and group them into an array" part that we're suggesting you revisit. Look at the actual content returned by curl, and think about what you're trying to do with it. Possibly what you need is an HTML parsing library like simple_html_dom. Or maybe you can split the content into sections and run regexes separately on each. The output you've got from preg_match clearly isn't what you want, so why stick with it?

Comment: unfortunately the content so bid to be inserted here   it's just content of the page as same as  this function file_get_contents    it just return all  website content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got something that will help. It will work with more inputs if you need. It might not work best if your second array has more than one breaking blank. Just working on updated code to solve such issues.

```
<?php

$arr1 = array("input", "", "", "another input", "", "", "yet another input", "");
$arr2 = array("", "p1", "p2", "", "p01", "p02", "","p11" );

$inp = array("comment" => $arr1, "images" => $arr2);

function mangle_arrays($input) {
    $out = array();
    $gen = 0;
    foreach($input as $key=>$val) {
        $id = $gen?-1:0;
        if ($gen) {
            foreach($val as $v) {
                if ($v) {
                    $out[$id][$key][] = $v;
                } else {
                    $id++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach($val as $v) {
                if ($v) {
                    $out[$id] = array();
                    $out[$id][$key] = $v;
                    $id++;
                }
            }
        }
        $gen++; 
    }
    return $out;
}

// your code goes here
echo "<pre>";
print_r(mangle_arrays($inp));
```

Results

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment] => input
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => p1
                    [1] => p2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [comment] => another input
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => p01
                    [1] => p02
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [comment] => yet another input
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => p11
                )

        )

)
```